# Unexpected line printing when using Scanner

Tags: java

I am using practice it for java, and have a question about the following exercise:

Write a complete program called "TheNameGame," where the user inputs a first and last name and a song in the following format is printed about their first, then last, name. Use a method to avoid redundancy.

What is your name? Fifty Cent
Fifty Fifty, bo-Bifty
Banana-fana fo-Fifty
Fee-fi-mo-Mifty
FIFTY!
Cent Cent, bo-Bent
Banana-fana fo-Fent
Fee-fi-mo-Ment
CENT!

This is the code I wrote for the answer:

```
public class TheNameGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first = scan.next();
        String last = scan.next();
        String newFirst = first.substring(1);
        String newLast = last.substring(1);

        System.out.println("What is your name? " + first + " " + last);
        playGame(first, newFirst);
        playGame(last, newLast);
    }
}

public static void playGame(String name, String nn) {
    System.out.println(name + " " + name + ", " + "bo-B" + nn);
    System.out.println("Banana-fana fo-F" + nn);
    System.out.println("Fee-fi-mo-M" + nn);
    System.out.println(name.toUpperCase() + "!");
}
```

And this is the output:

Fifty Cent
What is your name? Fifty Cent
Fifty Fifty, bo-Bifty
Banana-fana fo-Fifty
Fee-fi-mo-Mifty
FIFTY!
Cent Cent, bo-Bent
Banana-fana fo-Fent
Fee-fi-mo-Ment
CENT!

My question is; where is the first line (Fifty Cent) coming from?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the song come in? your exercise says to write first name, last name, then song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is; where is the first line (Fifty Cent) coming from?

It is not coming from anywhere. You input it, when you do

```
String first = scan.next();
String last = scan.next();
```

and `Fifty Cents` stays there on the screen. **Remember**, values you *input* **continue to stay on the screen**.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was very helpful. Using scanner is new to me, and I never thought of it staying on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to ask the question, and then get the input. You only have to make a couple of minor changes in your main method. Your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? "); //asks question first,
    String first = scan.next();              //THEN accepts first
    String last = scan.next();               //and last name
    String newFirst = first.substring(1);
    String newLast = last.substring(1);

    playGame(first, newFirst);
    playGame(last, newLast);
}
```

This will give the output:

```
What is your name? Fifty Cent
Fifty Fifty, bo-Bifty
Banana-fana fo-Fifty
Fee-fi-mo-Mifty
FIFTY!
Cent Cent, bo-Bent
Banana-fana fo-Fent
Fee-fi-mo-Ment
CENT!
```

It first asks the question, then accepts the first and last name of the user. Your issue was simply that your code was out of order.

Comment: @F.Moss is this answer ok? is there anything else you would like me to add?

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! Using scanner is new to me, so it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is; where is the first line (Fifty Cent) coming from?

When you enter :

```
Fifty Cent
```

`String first = scan.next();` will read `Fifty` and `String last = scan.next();` read `Cent`

for that when you print :

```
System.out.println("What is your name? " + first + " " + last);
```

It will print :

```
What is your name? Fifty Cent
```